# Python custom sort function for strings like 'Season Year'

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of the form 'Season Year':

`['Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Fall 2008', 'Spring 2008']`

And when sorted, the list should look like this:

`['Spring 2015', 'Fall 2014', 'Spring 2008', 'Fall 2008']`

Hence, the rules for sorting are:

1. First sort by year
2. Sort by season: 'Spring' then 'Fall'

I currently have a function called `lcmp` that I use on my list like this: `myList.sort(lcmp)`.

```
>>> def lcmp(a,b):
...     c = a.split()
...     d = b.split()
...     if(c[1]>d[1]):
...             if(c[0]>d[0]):
...                     return 1
...             else:
...                     return -1
...     else:
...             if(c[0]>d[0]):
...                     return 1
...             else:
...                     return 0
...
```

This works for sorting by year, but does not work for the season, even though I have specified that type of sorting. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just using `-year` to reverse the sort by year as the first key and the result of `seas != "Spring"` to break the ties using `key=sort_function`.

```
l = ['Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Fall 2008', 'Spring 2008']
def key(x):
    seas,year = x.split()
    return -int(year), seas != "Spring"

l.sort(key=key)
```

There is no way your function will work even if you use `myList.sort(key=lcmp)` as you are passing single strings so you don't have a and b to split. This will also work for python 2 or 3.

Comment: Or just sort twice using different key functions, which seems to be recommended by the doc.  This works because `sort()` is stable and is capable of taking advantage of nearly-sortedness.

Comment: Good, and for `seas` maybe the index of an iterable contains the seasons!

Comment: @Kasramvd, not sure I follow?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In this case your solution works very well, I said that for a general cases if we had more seasons ;)

Comment: I guess it means something like `seasondict = {"Spring": 0, "Summer": 1, ...}`.  One bonus is that you can have both "Fall" and "Autumn" and they give identical rank.

Comment: @Kasramvd, yep I was originally going to use a rank with a dict but the OP only seems to care about the two seasons

Comment: @CongMa. yep, that was my original thought but  it is a case either it is spring or not spring so in this case comparison works fine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah, anyway it's fantastic! I like the part `seas != "Spring"`

Comment: Never mind! I'm having trouble reading after a long night! Deleting my comment.

Answer (score 2):

One of the errors is that you don't check correctly for equality. What you return when `c[1] < d[1]` and `c[0] < d[0]`? The answer is zero, which is incorrect. Also you should declare `cmp` argument in sort. What you can do is the following:

```
seasons = {
    'Spring': 1,
    'Summer': 2,
    'Fall': 3,
    'Winter': 4,
}
def lcmp(a, b):
    a_season, a_year = a.split()
    b_season, b_year = b.split()
    return int(b_year) - int(a_year) or seasons[a_season] - seasons[b_season]

l = ['Fall 2014', 'Spring 2015', 'Fall 2008', 'Spring 2008']
l.sort(cmp=lcmp)
```

Result:

```
['Spring 2015', 'Fall 2014', 'Spring 2008', 'Fall 2008']
```

And if you want to play with iterators:

```
from itertools import ifilter, izip

def lcmp(a, b):
    it = (
        f(y) - f(x)
        for x, y, f in izip(
            reversed(a.split()),
            reversed(b.split()),
            (int, lambda _: -seasons[_])
        )
    )
    return next(ifilter(None, it), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also take into account the cases where the compared values are equal:

```
def lcmp(a,b):
    c = a.split()
    d = b.split()
    if c[1] > d[1]:
        return 1
    elif c[1] == d[1]:
        if c[0] > d[0]:
            return -1
        elif c[0] == d[0]:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        return -1
```

You can then sort the data using `myList.sort(lcmp)` or `myList.sort(cmp=lcmp)`